# Fetch Cross-tab grandtotal?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a cross tab inside a subreport. I need to fetch the grandtotal of cross tab and display it in a textobject under the cross tab. Any clue how this can be achieved ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Drag and drop the database or formula field you want into the detail section of the report. (Remove any unwanted guidelines / column headings that this generates.)
2. Right-click the inserted detail section item and select Insert > Summary... . Specify Sum, to be inserted in the same section as the datagrid is located. (Remove the detail section item, if you don't want it in the detail section.)
3. The total field can be dragged and dropped into position under the data grid. If you specifically want it in a text field, then insert a blank text field into the report under the data grid and then drag and drop the total field into it.

Comment: Thanks Mark, you were absolutely right. Any hint how I can display this field as toWords() rather then numbers ?

Comment: @Popo, instead of creating the numeric summary field as I suggested, create a formula field (called something like {@TotalInWords}) with the formula `ToWords (Sum ({Table.Value}))` and insert it into the report under the data grid as required.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I did what you told and it solved the problem =)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any criteria or special formula in the crosstab? If not, then you could probably just make a new formula `sum({table.field})` and put it wherever you like.

(If this subreport is grouped, you may want to use `sum({table.field},{table.group})`)